# Does XMLUNIT provide option to ignore certain elements in XML's for comparison?

Tags: java, xml, xmlunit

I am wondering if XMLUNIT provides a way to ignore some of the elements present in the XML before doing the comparison.For example, if I want to ignore  field which is randomly generated by the server.Is there anything available out of the box in XMLUnit to ignore certian elements or I need to write a custom *DifferenceListener* ?

Also, does it provide the elements name that do not match? If not, then what could be the best way to compare two XML which can allow me to ignore some elements and also provide me the elements names/values that does not match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid a custom `DifferenceListener` is the only way to go right now.  There is a feature request for XMLUnit2 (https://github.com/xmlunit/xmlunit/issues/26) that hasn't been implemented, yet.

Implementing the `DifferenceListener` may be a bit cumbersome since you'll not only receive `Difference`s for the elements you want to ignore but most likely also receive them for the number of children of the parent element.

Each `Difference` contains `NodeDetail`s for the nodes seen on the test and control side and the `NodeDetail` contains the DOM `Node` (which will be an `Element` in your case).

Comment: Thanks Stefan, I don't want to write anything complex here because I am writing this code for unit testing(testing the SOAP webservice response. ) Do you think, there is any other way by which we can determine what all elements does not match in the expcted and actual XML after comparision which I can put in the test case report.(we no longer have the requirement to ignore elements)

Comment: Sorry for the delay, Torukmakto.  Doesn't using `DetailedDiff` give you all the differences (likely more than one `Difference` object per perceived difference since missing nodes cause their parents to be different)?